# Image not inserting in sqlite database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Anyone Please Help me. I am trying to create a dictionary application in which i want to save words ,their meanings and picture with every word. I am trying to save all the words,images and meanings in sqlite database. The problem is that when i click on any word in the listview it shows me the word and definition but the image field is blank.Here is my class in which i am creating my database.

```
    public class DictionaryDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    byte[][] img = {
            DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
            DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
            DbBitmapUtility
                    .getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher)) };

    public DictionaryDataBase(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE Dict_Table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT NOT NULL, definition TEXT NOT NULL, image BLOB NOT NULL);");
        try {

            new DictionaryDB(context).addEntry(words, def, db, img);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }

    }
```

and this is the add entry method:

```
   public void addEntry(String[] word, String[] def, SQLiteDatabase db, byte[][] img) throws SQLiteException {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Dict_Table VALUES (" + i + 1 + ", '" + word[i] + "', '" + def[i] + "', '" + img[i]
                + "');");
    }
```

and this is the method which i am using to get the image:

```
    public byte[] Getimage() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new DictionaryDataBase(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Dict_Table WHERE word='" + MainActivity.item + "'", null);//MainActivity.item is the item which was clicked in the list view
    res.moveToFirst();
    byte[] img = res.getBlob(res.getColumnIndex(IMG_COL));
    if (!res.isClosed()) {
        res.close();
    }
    return img;

}
```

DbBitmapUtility.java:

```
   public class DbBitmapUtility {

// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}

}
```

activity_meaning.xml(This is the layout file for my words definition and image):

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.shehryar.dictionary.Meaning"
android:background="#2196F3" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Word"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdefinition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvword"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Definition" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvdefinition"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvdefinition"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_material" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

This is the onitemclick method of my listview which shows the list of words.

```
        @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
     item =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

     String def = db.GetDefinition();
    img=db.Getimage();

     Bundle basket = new Bundle();
     basket.putString("word", item);
     basket.putString("def", def);
     basket.putByteArray("img", img);


     Intent a= new Intent(this,Meaning.class);
     a.putExtras(basket);
     startActivity(a);
        //Toast.makeText(this, def, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and this is the meaning activity in which the result is showed:

Meaning.java:

```
    package com.shehryar.dictionary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Meaning extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meaning);
    String word,def;
    byte[] img;


    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    word=extras.getString("word");
    def=extras.getString("def");
    img=extras.getByteArray("img");
    Bitmap image=DbBitmapUtility.getImage(img);
    TextView tvword=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvword);
    TextView tvdef=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdefinition);
    TextView tvcheck= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcheck);
    ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tvword.setText(word);
    tvdef.setText(def);
    iv.setImageBitmap(image);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.meaning, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

If you need any other information I will provide it to you but please help me in this case. Its since 2-3 days, I have been stuck here.

Comment: listview shows all words of my dictionary.

Comment: Show the code that tries to show the image.

Comment: I have edited my question which includes the code to show the image

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you should not be doing it in SQLite. SQLite is a light DB with merely 250KB of size. When it comes to dictionary, SQLite wont be able to fulfil your desired request.
Try saving it on Server or Internal memory and save URL or path respectively in DB.

Comment: Ishant: but how can i access my pictures from the external storage if i run my app on any other device??

Comment: you have to keep it in internal memory. Application Sandbox. And since, this will need more memory as images increases, so better is to maintain an online db.